# How to stop Node.JS notification flow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, push-notification

I am experimenting with push-notifications sent from a `Node.js` app. Following some tutorial and examples, I now have a working mini-application to start with.

What it does is very basic, when it is loaded into the browser, a notification is fired every fifteen seconds and the user sees a message popping up each time.

***Here is the question: How should I stop the notification loop?***

At this point, the notifications keep coming every fifteen seconds even when I close the web page.

For reference I put here the two relevant files:

**index.js**:

```
const express = require('express'),
      webPush = require('web-push'),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
      path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const privateVapIdKey = process.env.privVapIdKey,
      publicVapIdKey = process.env.pubVapIdKey;

webPush.setVapidDetails(
    'mailto:myemail@example.com',
    publicVapIdKey,privateVapIdKey);

// Subscribe Route.
app.post('/subscribe',(req,res) => {
    const subscription = req.body; // Get Push Subscription Object.
    res.status(201).json({}); // Send 201. Resource created.

    // Do a lot of useful things ......
    .......
    // Create the PayLoad.
    const payload = JSON.stringify({
        title:'A big title!',
        ........
    });

    // Pass Object to sendNotification loop.
    const SECS = 15 * 1000;
    setInterval(() => {
        // Do a lot of useful things ......
        .......

        webPush.sendNotification(subscription,payload).catch(err => console.error(err));
    }, SECS);

});

const port = 5003;

const PORT = process.env.PORT || port;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));
```

**client.js**:

```
const publicVapIdKey = 'my-secret-3453754...pubVapIdKey';

// Chec for ServiceWorker.
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    send().catch(err => console.error(err));
}


// Register ServiceWorker, Register Push, Send Push.
async function send() {
    console.log("Registering ServiceWorker.");
    const register = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/worker.js', {
        scope: "/"
    });
    console.log('ServiceWorker registered.');

    console.log("Registering Push.");
    //register.pushManager.uns
    const subscription = await register.pushManager.subscribe({
        userVisibleOnly: true,
        applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(publicVapIdKey)
    });
    console.log('Push registered.');

    console.log("Sending Push.");
    await fetch('/subscribe', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(subscription),
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    });
    console.log('Push sent.');
}


function urlBase64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
    const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
    const base64 = (base64String + padding)
      .replace(/\-/g, '+')
      .replace(/_/g, '/');

    const rawData = window.atob(base64);
    const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
      outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return outputArray;
}
```

I suppose I need to add an */unsubscribe* route, after the

*await fetch('/subscribe', {*

inside client.js. But I am not 100% sure and if this is the thing to do, how can I write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would need to do is to keep track of your `setInterval` function and then use the `clearInterval` function like this :

```
const SECS = 15 * 1000;
const notificationLoop = setInterval(() => {
        // Do a lot of useful things ......
        webPush.sendNotification(subscription,payload).catch(err => console.error(err));
    }, SECS);
```

When you want to stop it :

```
clearInterval(notificationLoop);
```

More informations about [clearInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

Be sure to keep the reference of your `notificationLoop` to prevent it from being undefined.

Comment: Your suggestion is very interesting, but the page you mention refers to something working on the client side (the example given is a timer, with a button to stop it). In my case the notifications are fired from the server. The situation is different.

Comment: After reading quite a bit, I presume I need to add some unsubscribe feature, beside the existing subscribe feature. But I am not sure how to do it.